# Invalidate JWT Token only after a period of inactivity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm using [Tymon JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package in my Laravel project, and I need to invalidate the token of the connected user after 4 hours of inactivity.
In the config file of the package I can set the `TTL` time for a token as : `'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 240),` and the user will be logged out every 4 hours even if he was active, but I only want that to happen if the user wasn't active during the whole 4 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the token expire after the user goes idle, you have to reissue a token on every request with a new expiration

I believe you are also looking for `exp`, not `ttl`.

Tokens are minted by the server at a specific time. You cannot modify a token, but you can make a new one. Only the server can mint tokens. Most of the time, the server uses a Public-Private key, and signs the token with the private key. Therefore the user cannot modify it without failing verification.

Just set the token the next time the user makes a request. That is a common practice when using JWTs. It isn't much overhead to set it, and that will take care of the '4 hours of inactivity' signout.